# Find and replace not working on values containing a quotation mark in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file containing lines similar to:

```
"This is a test \" sentence"
```

I'm trying to remove all occurrences of \" and replace them with nothing using this find and replace:

```
$fixedline = $line -replace  '\"',''
```

The result I want is this:

```
"This is a test sentence"
```

but instead I get:

```
This is a test \ sentence
```

What is the correct syntax for this? I've tried multiple combinations of quotes and double quotes but still no luck.

I've also tried setting the \" value to a variable and calling the variable instead with the same result.

**EDIT** Solution found, the escape character for \ is a double backslash so the correct syntax would be '\"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked:

```
$fixedLine = $line -replace '\\"', ''
```